# Empirical Bayes prediction

Tags: predictive-models, glmm, empirical-bayes

I've been working with a GLMM in SAS. Using the proc GLIMMIX procedure, I've extracted the EB estimates of the random-effects.

I was looking into empirical Bayes estimates and their predictive power.
So I was wondering, how does one use the empirical Bayes estimates to predict something in a hierarchical model?

Are there any advantages to use these estimates for prediction? Because aren't the estimates shrunk towards the mean structure of the model in comparison the true random-effects? Which seems like quite a disadvantage.